# My listView is showing empty rows after specifying some conditions

Tags: android, listview, view

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        final LinearLayout itemView;

         if(convertView == null){

                 itemView = (LinearLayout) mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sms_layout, parent, false);
               final TextView smsMsg = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewForSMS);
              final Sms sms=mEntries.get(position);
              if(sms.getAddress().contains("5556")){
                /*itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/
               smsMsg.setText(sms.getAddress()+" :\n  "+sms.getMsg());
               smsMsg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    plum.ShowSendMsgLayout(sms.getMsg().split(":")[0]);

                }
            });
              }

         }else{

             itemView=(LinearLayout)convertView;
            /* if(sms.getMsg().contains(" ")){
                 itemView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             }*/
         }

        return itemView;
    }



    public void upDateEntries(List<Sms> entries) {
        mEntries = new ArrayList<Sms>();
         notifyDataSetChanged();
        mEntries = entries;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

This is my code of list adapter. i gave a condition that messages only from emulator 5556 appear in my list view. But messages of other emulator are to be seen as blank i.e an empty row without any action performance. please suggest a solution to the code to eliminate those empty rows.

Answer (score 0):

> This is my code of list adapter. i gave a condition that messages only
>   from emulator 5556 appear in my list view. But messages of other
>   emulator are to be seen as blank

Number of rows in ListView is depend on which value is returned `getCount` method method of Adapter. ListView showing all messages because probably adapter data-source contains all messages.

To fix this issue call `remove` method for adapter if message not contain `5556` :

```
if(sms.getAddress().contains("5556")){

  // your code here...
}else{
  // remove item from adapter
  remove(position);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: this does not work for me... but the above code does...thank you...:
)

Comment: @SwapnaAkella: what do you mean why not working? are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be verified at the time when you add the Sms to your data list. Your should not add the Sms if it does not match that condition. I change the code for you, have a try:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView =  mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sms_layout, parent, false);
    }
    final TextView smsMsg = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewForSMS);
    final Sms sms=mEntries.get(position);
     smsMsg.setText(sms.getAddress()+" :\n  "+sms.getMsg());
     smsMsg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          plum.ShowSendMsgLayout(sms.getMsg().split(":")[0]);

      }
    });

   return convertView;
}



public void upDateEntries(List<Sms> entries) {
   mEntries.clear();
   for(Sms sms : entries){
       if(sms.getAddress().contains("5556")){
           mEntries.add(sms);
       }
   }
   notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```